# symfony 2.0.22 request header null

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.0

I was working with symfony 2.0.12 but I have this problem: the page is not updated, always returns null.

```
public function cambiarlocaleAction($idioma)
{
    $this->get('session')->setLocale($idioma);
    $request = $this->get('request');
    return new Response ($request->headers->get('referer'));
    return $this->redirect($request->headers->get('referer'));
}
```

`$request->headers->get('referer')` always null why? in symfony 2.0.14 work.

Comment: Why do you return twice ?

Comment: use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\HeaderBag; working correctly thanks.

Comment: If you find the answer, post it and accept it

Answer (score 1):

There is no guarantee the header `referer` is sent with the request. Typically if the user enters the URL directly, it's not present (and therefore if you try to retrieve it, the result is `null`). Even when user is following a link the browser is not obligated to send that header.